# How to read and write byte array line by line in text file

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to record binary message packets in text file, one message per one line. After that I will read line by line to parse into meaningful message.

I looked into binaryWriter class and found write method which writes byte array but could not find writeLine method.

Please suggest good approach to record byte array in text file.

Comment: Please give examples of what you mean by “binary message packets”, and “text file”. `BinaryWriter` has no `WriteLine` method because only text has the concept of a “line” so you are confusing things.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve downvotes; this is based around a (likely common) misconception of how binary is represented when written to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to save binary data to a text file, but also have line breaks, you might want to use `Convert.ToBase64String`.  This will ensure you don't have any line feed characters inside of your binary data, that would inadvertently break the line.

Answer (score 1):

When you write binary to a file; you aren't writing this:

> 1011100111011
>
> 0110101010101
>
> 1000110100101

Because thats *not actually binary*. That is textual (human-readable) representation of binary. A real binary file represented by text is the ASCII/Unicode encoding of the binary. Its very hard to read; if you want proof; just open up a PNG file in Notepad++.

Thus; having line endings for a binary file **makes no sense at all**. Hence, no `WriteLine` method on BinaryWriter.

If you want to write out the binary above; you need to format it as a string, like so:

```
textWriter.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(value, 2));
```

Now, you probably *can* just use `BinaryWriter` (that is how you write byte[] after all) but just don't expect it to be human readable! You would then use `BinaryReader` to deserialize your written file.

Comment: Bradley you are right, it doesn't make sense to have WriteLine method in case of bytes and I agree with your solution to convert to string first and then write in line.